# How to make list of 1st and last day of month using only DateTime?

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I want to make array of previous month 1st and last day. From my starting   `\DateTime $date=2018-04-30`. When I change my starting `\DateTime` to `2018-05-31` and my expected result is an array that contains:

```
[
  ['2018-03-01', 2018-03-31],
  ['2018-02-01', 2018-02-28],
  ['2018-01-01', 2018-01-31],
  ['2018-01-01', 2018-03-31],
  ['2017-03-01', 2018-03-31],
]
```

I have currently done:

```
$monthAgoStart = clone $date;
$monthAgoEnd = clone $date;
$month2agoStart = clone $date;
$month2agoEnd = clone $date;
$month3agoStart = clone $date;
$month3agoEnd = clone $date;
$currentYearStart = clone $date;
$yearAgo = clone $date;
$monthAgoStart->modify('first day of previous month');
$monthAgoEnd->modify('last day of previous month');
$month2agoStart->modify('first day of this month')->modify('-2 months');
$month2agoEnd = new \DateTime($month2agoEnd->modify('-1 months')->format('y-m-0'));
$month3agoStart= new \DateTime($month3agoStart->modify('-3 months')->format('y-m-1'));
$month3agoEnd = new \DateTime($month3agoEnd->modify('-3 months')->format('y-m-0'));
$currentYearStart->modify('first day of January');
$yearAgo->modify('-12 months');
```

Result array:

```
$dates = [
  'ago1month' => ["start" => $monthAgoStart, "end" => $monthAgoEnd],
  'ago2month' => ["start" => $month2agoStart, "end" => $month2agoEnd],
  'ago3month' => ["start" => $month3agoStart, "end" => $month3agoEnd],
  'yearStart' => ["start" => $currentYearStart, "end" => $monthAgoEnd],
  'yearAgo' => ["start" => $yearAgo, "end" => $monthAgoEnd],
];
```

My code generates:

```
{"ago1month":{
         "start":{"date":"2018-03-01"},
         "end":{"date":"2018-03-31"}
    },
    "ago2month":{
         "start":{"date":"2018-02-01"},
         "end":{"date":"2018-02-28 "}
    },
    "ago3month":{
         "start":{"date":"2018-01-01 "},
         "end":{"date":"2017-12-31"}
    },
    "yearStart":{ 
        "start":{"date":"2018-01-01"},
        "end":{"date":"2018-03-31"}
    },
"yearAgo":{ 
        "start":{"date":"2017-04-30"},
        "end":{"date":"2018-03-31 "}
    }
}
```

What is best option to solve my problem? I was planning to make strings and create `new DateTime` for each array record, but want to be sure if there are no other way to do this.
Still wrong:
`"yearAgo":{ "start":{"date":"2017-04-30"}}`
`"ago3month":{"end":{"date":"2017-12-31"}}`

---edit---

I used Carbon library that solves my issue. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153903/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-previous-month-with-carbon-laravel),

Comment: I don't understand your expected array. Especially `['2018-01-01', 2018-01-31],
  ['2018-01-01', 2018-03-31],` Do you meant 2018-01-31 instead of 2018-03-31? But then it would be duplicate with the one above..

Comment: Why would -12 months from 4/30 or 5/31 return `2017-03-01`?

Comment: @Xatenev it seems only the first 3 lines are the previous months, the last two are supposed to be last quarter and last year

Comment: I think you'd have a much easier time if you used `DateTimeImmutable` instead of `DateTime`. You wouldn't need to clone anything, and you'd avoid your underlying objects being changed when you modify them.

Comment: It feels like you have working code.  If you are seeking refinement advice, perhaps migrate to CodeReview.  If you have a "problem", it isn't clear to me.

Comment: @mickmackusa My code doesn't work as expected. I don't want any `format` function to use and get my code working. Should I create `new DateTime (string)` for each element of my array? No other solutions?

Comment: @mickmackusa [Cross-posted and about to get closed on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/200084/52915). The question should've been cleaned up here instead of cross-posted.

Comment: @Mast looks like the OP pulled it.  I did say that the question was unclear to me.

Answer (score 2):

When retrieving the last day of the month, you should use `t` from the [date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

You can also simplify your code and make it much easier to read by cloning $date when you need it or using DateTimeImmutable.

```
$month3agoEnd = (clone $date)->modify('-3 months')->format('Y-m-t');
```

This turns out to be `2018-03-31` as expected.  Using `Y-m-0` returns `2018-03-0` which you have processed inside of a new \DateTime object, so your code is actually written as:

```
 $month3agoEnd = new DateTime('2018-03-0');
```

This actually returns a new DateTime instance set to `2018-02-28` so I'm not sure how you managed to get `2017-12-31`.

Comment: `$month3agoEnd = (clone $date)->modify('-3 months')->format('Y-m-t');` 
What about php 5.6 solution?

Comment: @pvaitonis  This won't work in 5.6, but 5.6 is almost end of life, and I'm not aware of any OS distribution supporting 5.6 longer.  So I wouldn't recommend building new projects for 5.6.  http://php.net/supported-versions.php.  You could still use DateTimeImmutable or just use clone $date on a separate line.